# javapoet - how to implement "extends" and "implements"

Tags: java, javapoet

Using Javapoet, how to implement the following:

1. class A extends class B
2. class C implements Interface D

In the javadoc, it is mentioned how to create interfaces.

Answer (score 26):

Use `TypeSpec.Builder.superclass()` for extends, and `TypeSpec.Builder.addSuperinterface()` for implements.

Comment: Thanks so much Jesse.

Comment: I am creating a class implementing Serializable interface. How to write code to generate Serial version id?

Comment: @urSus wanna send a pull request?

Answer (score 11):

Suppose you want to generate a `Dummy` class that extends `Exception` class and implements the `Serializable` interface. The generate code is:

```
...
TypeSpec typeSpec = TypeSpec.classBuilder("Dummy")
  .addSuperinterface(Serializable.class) 
  .superclass(Exception.class) 
  .build();

JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("sample.javapoet", typeSpec).build();
...
```

And the generated code will be:

```
package sample.javapoet;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.Exception;

class Hoge extends Exception implements Serializable {
}
```